# Where can I find mirrors for Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, download, mirror

We can download Netbeans from main website using their decision concerning which server to use.

Is there available mirror lists for Netbeans IDE downloads?

I don't see any mirror out there though the main website can point to many servers (after testing with different proxies).

Is there any policy concerning about the download of free Netbeans IDE?

Comment: If you look at the links given in the answer below, you will see that Netbeans no longer allows mirroring of binaries, but uses a content delivery network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want:

http://netbeans.org/about/os/mirrors.html

http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1306.html

Comment: You can also find [official?] torrents to save them some $$$.